# I can't find dots on an unit cirlce from degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I want to have coordinates of  places all around of the circle

```
Debug.Log("Degree: " + Degree);

x = Mathf.Cos(Degree);
y = Mathf.Sin(Degree);

Debug.Log("x: " + x + "   y: " + y);
```

my outputs are:

> Degree: 60
> x: -0.952413   y: -0.3048106

> Degree: 120
> x: 0.814181   y: 0.5806112

> Degree: 180
> x: -0.5984601   y: -0.8011526

> Degree: 240
> x: 0.3257813   y: 0.9454452

> Degree: 300
> x: -0.02209662   y: -0.9997559

> Degree: 360
> x: -0.2836911   y: 0.9589157

why doesn't this work? simple geomatry I know says this should give me positions of every 60 degree

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641798/how-to-find-x-and-y-coordinates-on-a-flipped-circle-using-javascript-methods

Comment: Convert degrees to radians before you Sin and Cos

Comment: from the [Mathf.Cos Unity3d documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Cos.html)  "f  The input angle, in radians."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Pac0 said in the comments

> from the Mathf.Cos [Unity3d documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Cos.html) "f The input angle, in radians."

```
            Degree = (float)((Math.PI / 180) * Degree);

            x = Mathf.Cos(Degree);
            y = Mathf.Sin(Degree);
```

Edit: Sorry added the code that actually fixed my problem

Comment: Rather than putting in the comment text, can you please modify your answer and add the proper piece of code which solved your problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry I fixed it now